# How do I transfer my Firefox profile from Windows 7 to Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, firefox

My Windows 7 broke up and now I am on Ubuntu. I can't load Windows itself, only command line, system restore and others didn't work.

I can however access my Windows 7 files from Ubuntu.

Is it possible to copy all Firefox bookmarks, passwords etc. from Windows 7 to Ubuntu's Firefox?

Comment: Firefox has the ability to sync passwords I would use that.

Comment: By Mozilla, you mean Firefox?

Comment: @Ramhound With his Windows broken, how would that work?

Comment: @slhck: Yeah, Firefox.

Comment: simply copy it from the windows folder to the linux folder... Or does that not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your Windows partition is mounted as `/mnt` and that your Windows username is `hey`, first copy the (randomly named) old profile directory to your Ubuntu account:

```
cp -r /mnt/Users/hey/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/*.default ~/.mozilla/firefox/win7profile
```

Then quit Firefox and edit the `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` file, changing `StartWithLastProfile=1` to `StartWithLastProfile=0` and adding the following to the end:

```
[Profile1]
Name=win7profile
IsRelative=1
Path=win7profile
```

Restart Firefox. It should then allow you to select which profile you want to use.

Comment: Very nice. I have one computer that I  have been running different browsers to maintain different configurations, is it this easy to run separate profiles. I can't believe this is my first glimpse of this.

Comment: @PleaseStand: It doesn't work... :( And where can I find that file in Ubuntu (I am noob).

Comment: @hey: In the cp command, replace /mnt/Users/hey/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/*.default with your windows7 firefox profile directory.